# Firebase Crash and Throws Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, android, websocket, firebase

I am Using Firebase client for android in my project and for last 4 days it throws random `NullPointerException` while connecting to Firebase.

Here is my stacktrace that I have found on BugSense:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
1at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocketHandshake.verifyServerHandshakeHeaders(WebSocketHandshake.java:95)
2at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:147)
```

Thanks in advance in this regard

Comment: It really helps if you share a bit of the code that is causing the problem. As you can see that your question already got to votes-to-close, based on the fact that no code is included. Since it is clearly identified in the stacktrace, I looked it up here: https://github.com/firebase/TubeSock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/firebase/tubesock/WebSocketHandshake.java. But we have no idea if that version is the one you use.

Comment: It looks like the version of tubesock you are using is not the latest (the call to `verifyServerHandshakeHeaders` is no longer on line 147 of `WebSocket.run`. I recommend that you reproduce the problem in a debugger and check what headers **are** being returned from the server (it seems like the `Upgrade` header is missing). If debugging/reproducing is not possible, you should probably upgrade to the latest version of tubesock. That might be a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks Frank for replying yes my library is not upto-date i will update it and then try.